# Speech recognization other languages apart from English in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I am trying to convert audio to text. The audio is not in English but in Dutch. I am unable to convert the Dutch audio to text. The code works only for English audios. I am not sure if I need to include some functions or options for the code to recognise other languages as well. Below is the code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile('audio.wav') as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = (r.recognize_google)
        print(text)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="nl-NL")
```

Comment: Hi luigigi, ah ok, I thought so there would be options to include the languages. But I didn't know how. Thank you so much. I am gonna try and let you know soon.

Comment: I wish I could post the full code, but I dont have enough previlages to do so!! but it works,..

Comment: i am glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

you can do any language you just need to know what is your countries domains like for instance German would be: de-DE

Comment: Please provide a code snippet; this might be really helpful.